# Creating a simple proxy server with nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to create a simple proxy server that will allow embedding older HTTP websites within an iFrame on a newer HTTPS site.

Ideally, I would like to create something like this: https://proxy.my.domain?url=http://old.site

Loading this URL would load all of the content on http://old.site from the proxy address. The url argument can be any arbitrary URL, including https sites, or direct file links and everything should load as you would normally expect.

The common suggestion I've found online is to use `proxy_pass $arg_url;` - however, this works for the initial request, but fails on all subsequent requests such as inline images.

It fails because it does not maintain the correct hostname and so attempts to load https://proxy.my.domain/example.jpg instead of https://proxy.my.domain?url=http://old.site/example.jpg

The recommended solution Iv found is to include a HOST header `proxy_set_header Host $host;` however, this fails because it passes the full proxy host to the server being proxied, which breaks webservers that depend on a hostname to deliver the correct website - e.g. if a particular server is hosting default.com and nondefault.com, it will always load default.com even when you request nondefault.com

Additionally passing the request url `proxy_set_header Host $arg_url;` also fails because host headers cannot have the http:// protocol defined, and removing the protocol from the argument seems to result in it behaving like a redirect.

How can I configure Nginx to act as a simple URL-based proxy server? Or is there a better solution that has illuded me?